# Why does working with fresh copy of Data brings better results then old one in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file

While working with simple code reading data from a file in Linux,I had a list of 100 files created a year ago, each one of them with size of 2GB (200GB for all files). The running time of working of those files was almost twice the time if I created a fresh copy of the same files, In almost the same path. It was almost an hour different for the New copy (I used `cp` command, I didn't recreated them). 
No other programs were running at the background. Any reasons why?
The command I used was:

```
$ cp -rp /path/old/ /path/new/
```

So it was recursive.It took 30 minutes.

```c
int main(void)
{
    char file[] = "/path/to/my/file";
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "wb");
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(file_size);
    fread(buf, file_size, 1 , fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I could think of is, that the old files might be fragmented to hell and the new ones arent. But that is just a wild guess.

Comment: Did you copy them into the same directory? If not: did you use to have a huge amount of files in the old directory? Even after deleting the files from a directory which used to be full of files (tens/hundreds of thousands), the node info is retained which could lead to lagging when accessing that directory (and actually takes up a lot of space for nothing).

Comment: There are to few details to really say anything, but if the new, copied files, are faster to read it might be because the files (or parts of them) are cached already since you just copied them. Or that the copying places them in a more optimal place on the hard-drive (if you're using rotating platter drives and not an SSD). But I'm just ***guessing***, there could be *thousands* of other reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the folder to a brother folder meaning: /path/old/ and the new   /path/new. And how come some files are still in the cache, the cache size of L1 is less then 20MB and the size of L2 is not coming close for 10GB.. right?

Comment: A modern operating system have many levels of caching outside the hardware caches for the CPU and it cores. And how did you copy? File by file? The whole directory recursively? Please edit your question to include that information, and preferably the actual command(s) used.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Thanks, I edited. The command I used was cp -rp /path/old/ /path/new/ , So it was recursive.It took 30 minutes

Comment: Try the same thing, but flush the OS disk caches after the copying. On Linux, write "3" (as text) to "/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches". It is likely that just after you have made the copy, much of the data just written is cached in main memory.

Comment: You don't have an SSD from Samsung, do you?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I dont, I will try flush the caches. But what do you mean wrtie 3 as test to the file in the path : /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches?

Comment: Linux likely keeps recently read files in memory as long as enough memory is available. Can you compare the result of copying the file to you reading out the entire file (e.g. with `cat file >/dev/null`) and then working on it?

Comment: @raptor0102: The file /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches isn't a real file stored on disk, but a virtual file that is used as an interface to the disk caching system. To flush the caches, write "3" to that file, for example like this (as root): `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: *The running time of working of those files was almost twice the time if I created a fresh copy of the same files*  How big are the files?  What type of disk(s) are they stored on?  If the files are large enough that caching doesn't help performance, and the disk layout is causing the newer files to be stored on the outer cylinders of the disk(s), you could see just about a 2x performance gain, as the outer cylinders of disks can stream data faster than the inner cylinders (outer cylinders are larger, holding more data per cylinder, so there's more data passing under the heads per sec)